# Использование союза «и»

Tags: союзы, и

Возник вопрос: можно ли в предложении «Кстати, рекомендуем к прочтению небольшое эссе из сентябрьского номера про этих замечательных и колючих зверьков на букву Ё» использовать союз «и»?

Answer (score 1):

Определения *замечательные* и *колючие* — неоднородные, запятая между ними не нужна. Постановка между ними союза **и** в предложении ничем не оправдана.

"Кстати, рекомендуем к прочтению небольшое эссе из сентябрьского номера про этих *замечательных колючих* зверьков на букву Ё" — правильный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо. Но является ли это ошибкой? Или автор вправе использовать "и"?

Comment: Теоретически автор вправе использовать "и", но я бы не советовал ему это делать.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Союз использовать можно, вот "к прочтению" – это ой... Будьте проще: рекомендуем прочитать.